# Compare rows across columns - classic ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

I have a situation where I want to test for differences between rows and columns in my data frame:

```
  ID          Cond1A   Cond1B     Cond2A   Cond2B
  Sample1      2000    2311       2323     2324
  Sample2      2424    1313       2324     4546
  Sample3      1213    3413       2342     3353
```

How do I test if Sample1 is different from Sample 2 and 3 across Condition 1 and 2 (where A and B are replicates). I prefer to do it in R, but really don't find a good way.

Comment: I think you may need to expand on your question to get a useful answer. What do these numbers represent? How many samples do you have? What is the fundamental research question you are trying to answer?

Comment: I have about 2000 samples. They represent genes. NUmbers are expression values for the genes in different conditions (cells).